Grouping and collapsing consecutive periods
The business requirement is to collapse consecutive periods into 1 row using SQL in Databricks. If a row's end date is one day before the next rows start date, then these 2 rows are considered to be the same period.
Here is a demo data set:



row
id
start_date
end_date




1
a
2024-05-03
2024-05-06


2
a
2024-05-07
2024-05-10


3
a
2024-05-13
2024-05-17


4
a
2024-05-18
2024-05-22


5
a
2024-05-23
2024-06-27



In this data set, row 1 and 2 should be of the same period, and so do row 3 to 5.
The desired output is:



row
id
start_date
end_date




1
a
2024-05-03
2024-05-10


2
a
2024-05-13
2024-06-27



I tried to use the lead and lag window functions to get previous rows' end date but this approach doesn't work if you have more than 2 rows of consecutive periods.
Thanks very much for your help

This is typically known as Gaps and Island problem. You need to create a dummy column to identify your continuous date range and then find the min and max values based on that column -
SELECT id, MIN(start_date) start_date, MAX(end_date) end_date
  FROM (SELECT id, start_date, end_date, SUM(rn) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) sum_flag
          FROM (SELECT id, start_date, end_date,
                       CASE WHEN start_date - 1 <> LAG(end_date) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date)
                                 THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                       END rn
                 FROM demo
               ) T
       ) X
 GROUP BY id, sum_flag;

Demo.

Thanks a lot Ankit. Exactly what I need
